# Using child module property in parent pom

Tags: maven, web-applications

I have a parent pom which defines maven-war-plugin.

```
<plugin> 
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
 <version>2.6</version> 
 <configuration> 
   <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
   <warName>${warname}</warName>
 </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

And in the child pom I am declaring the property `${warname}`. When I try to deploy the child web module using Eclipse's 'Run as server' option the warname property is not resolved. Please let me know if this kind of configuration is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. You would have to set the property in the parent-pom and use it in the child-module. The properties only work from parent to child and not the other way around.